# URL to Ping for Offline Detection

Tags: javascript

I have a web application that needs to periodically check whether the user is offline.

Currently, I have on check that polls our API. This will tell the user whether our server is online. I would additionally like for the to be a check as to whether their device has internet access.

Outside of using navigator.onLine, what is a reliable URL to poll that is sanctioned for this purpose?

Comment: This may be a solution for you as well https://superuser.com/questions/1248025/url-for-testing-internet-connectivity

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one.

Each OS does their own captive portal detection, and determines online/offline state from this.  (That is, if they bother to do this at all.)  Some browsers do their own thing as well.

Nothing is sanctioned for general use.  You'll have to deploy something yourself for this.  Specifically what you do depends on specifically what problem you're trying to solve.

What is "online" anyway?  You could put up a simple static web server, but what if non-HTTP requests are firewalled out?  What if some corporate network has their own certs installed on each client and they replace the page with one of theirs?  What if someone was online 10 seconds ago, but no longer is?  How long do you wait to see if connectivity is lost?  What if the user has connectivity, but it's at some useless 300 bps speed?

There is no generic solution.  `navigator.onLine` is as close as you get.